# Find the absolute minimum in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given. Array A represents numbers on a tape.

Any integer P, such that 0 < P < N, splits this tape into two non-empty parts: A[0], A[1], ..., A[P − 1] and A[P], A[P + 1], ..., A[N − 1].

The difference between the two parts is the value of: `|(A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P − 1]) − (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[N − 1])|`

In other words, it is the absolute difference between the sum of the first part and the sum of the second part.

For example, consider array A such that:

```
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 2
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 3
```

We can split this tape in four places:

```
 P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7
 P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5
 P = 3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1
 P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7
```

Write a function:

```
  class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
```

that, given a non-empty array A of N integers, returns the minimal difference that can be achieved.

For example, given:

```
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 2
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 3
```

the function should return 1, as explained above.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [2..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000..1,000].

For the above problem, I have tried below approach,

```
    int firstSum = 0;
    int secondSum = 0;
    int tot = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    List<Integer> col = new ArrayList<>();

    int k=0;
    while(m<A.length)
    {

        firstSum = firstSum + A[k]; 
        for(int i=m; i<A.length; i++)
        {
            secondSum = secondSum + A[i];
        }
        k++;
    }


    System.out.println("Min DIfference: " +tot);
```

As the above works fine but its time complexity reaches `O(N*N)` which is not acceptable.
Please help to get some Idea which algorithm is suitable for this problem.

Comment: Why so many close votes ?

Comment: @OleV.V. nope definitely not sir, I tried some algorithms but the best I can get is above only.

Comment: Apparently you are not looking for help with coding. To me this seems to be rather a question of algorithms and math.

Comment: Isn't this just a trivial problem?

Comment: Can the array contain negative numbers too? As an aside if the length is 1, the task is impossible since no integral `p` exists that fulfils `0 < p < n`.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes it can consist of negative values as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be the below approach can help to improve complexity:

I would first make a cumulative sum of the elements, i.e for your example above something like:

```
int[] A = {3,1,2,4,3};

for(int i = 1; i< A.length; i++){
    A[i] = A[i-1]+A[i];
}
```

to produce:

```
[3, 4, 6, 10, 13]
```

and in a second loop calculate the absolute difference from the total sum which is at index `[A.length-1]` each sub-sum at each index `i`

```
|A[i] - (A[A.length-1] + A[i])|
```

your method could look something like:

```
public static int solution(int[] A){
    for(int i = 1; i< A.length; i++){
        A[i] = A[i-1]+A[i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i< A.length-1; i++){
        if(Math.abs(A[i]-A[A.length-1]+A[i]) < min){
            min = Math.abs(A[i]-A[A.length-1]+A[i]);
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

You can use also the built in method `Arrays.parallelPrefix(int[] array, IntBinaryOperator op)` to cumulate the elements of the array and get rid of the first loop. From the javadoc

> Cumulates, in parallel, each element of the given array in place, using the supplied function. For example if the array initially holds [2, 1, 0, 3] and the operation performs addition, then upon return the array holds [2, 3, 3, 6]. Parallel prefix computation is usually more efficient than sequential loops for large arrays.

Code using `Arrays.parallelPrefix`

```
public static int solution(int[] A){
    Arrays.parallelPrefix(A, Integer::sum);        
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i< A.length-1; i++){
        if(Math.abs(A[i]-A[A.length-1]+A[i]) < min){
            min = Math.abs(A[i]-A[A.length-1]+A[i]);
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: excellent, I have been banging my head for a long time, thank you so much.

Comment: would you mind to share the thought process behind this? Did you follow any algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity can be reduced by using the concept of prefix sum.

**Make use of 2 prefix sum arrays:**

1) forward_prefix_sum (Sum of array elements from left to right)

2) backward_prefix_sum (Sum of array elements from right to left).

Finally, traverse the array to calculate the minimum difference.

`answer = min(abs(forward_prefix_sum[i] - backward_prefix_sum[i]))` for (0 <= i < n)

`Time complexity: O(n)`